# Concatenate block of memory into a wire array?

Tags: memory, concatenation, verilog

In my project I have something like this:

```
reg [15:0] mem [3:0];
wire [63:0] data;
```

I know I can concatenate the mem into `data` like this:

```
assign data = {mem[3], mem[2], mem[1], mem[0]};
```

but it becomes some bad work when the memory grows big:

```
reg [3:0] mem [255:0];
wire [1023:0] data;
```

I'm afraid writing something like this isn't going to be a good idea, even I can write some other Python or Ruby script to generate such a line.

```
assign data = {mem[255], ..........., mem[0]};
summon_cthulhu();
```

Is there any better approach to do this?

Note: This is not an XY problem - it's the exact problem that I want to solve.

Comment: If you're targeting an FPGA, keep in mind that this will make it impossible to implement the array as block RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a generate-for loop

```
genvar ii;
for (ii=0;ii<256;ii=ii+1)
   assign data[ii*16+:16] = mem[ii];
```

Comment: What is this index `[ii*16+:16]`?

Comment: Can I do this in a procedural block (`initial` or `always`)? It seems to be a syntax error there.

Comment: You can't make an assignment to a wire in a procedural block, but you can use similar syntax to write to `reg`

Comment: in system verilog you could do this as well: `assign data = {>>{mem}};`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

```
parameter  MEM_WIDTH = 4;
parameter  MEM_DEPTH = 256;
localparam DATA_SIZE = (MEM_WIDTH * MEM_DEPTH);

reg[MEM_WIDTH-1:0]mem[MEM_DEPTH-1:0];
reg[DATA_SIZE-1:0]data;

always@(*)
begin
 for(i=0; i<MEM_DEPTH; i=i+1)
 begin
   data[i*MEM_WIDTH +: MEM_WIDTH] = mem[i];
 end
end
```